# document.getElementById("").src - file path is changing, but image is not

Tags: javascript, image, getelementbyid

I am simply trying to change the source of an image using JavaScript. Watching in Firebug shows me that when my function is called, the image paths are changing, however, the image itself is not switching. Has this ever occurred to anyone?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle of it to show us.

Comment: Are you sure the images are diffrent?

Comment: Tough to say without any code to play with...

Comment: I resolved the issue. There were multiple items with the same ID being created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

When are you loading your image? You could use a preloader 
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5214317.html
You should show the function you are using to change the image, so we can understand what it is a happening